# OpenGL Reconstructing Position from Depth

Tags: opengl, depth-buffer, deferred-rendering

I know this has been asked a lot of time before but none of those answers fixed my problem.
I try to implement deferred shading and to do so I need to reconstruct the world space position from the depth. (Having a position texture in the gbuffer would be a waste of data)

**The calculation works fine for rotationing the camera (-> moving the mouse) but as soon as I move the camera (-> pressing wasd) they get weird.**

[image: Cube front]
[image: Cube with camera rotated (correct)]
[image: Cube front with camera moved (incorrect)]
[image: Cube with camera moved and rotated (incorrect)]

GLSL:

```
vec4 screenSpacePosition = vec4(pass_Texture * 2.0 - 1.0, texture(gbuffer_texture[2],     pass_Texture).r, 1);
vec4 worldSpacePosition = invertedViewProjection  * screenSpacePosition;
vec3 finalPosition = worldSpacePosition.xyz / worldSpacePosition.w;
```

gbuffer_texture[2] is the depth attachment of OpenGL.
invertedViewProjection is the matrix I used to render the scene inverted on the CPU.

Comment: What's your question/problem?

Comment: @Fault Facepalm@me. I would help to descripe the problem.

Comment: You need to use a linear depth value for your computation (mapped to the range [-1, 1]). Check out the answer over here for how to get the linear value: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19750351/reconstructed-position-from-depth-leads-to-incorrect-lighting

Answer (score 4):

The result sampled from `gbuffer_texture[2]` will be in the [0, 1] range, but in OpenGL, NDC space ranges from -1 to 1 along all three axes.  (This is different from D3D, where the NDC space ranges from 0 to 1 along the z axis.)

So, you need to multiply the depth result by 2 and subtract 1 to convert the range to [-1, 1], just as you're doing already for the xy components of `screenSpacePosition`.  Then you'll have the proper NDC position, and you can apply the inverse view-projection matrix as you're doing.

FYI, there are more optimized ways to do this that don't require a full matrix multiply per pixel.  However, it's a good idea to get things working in a simple way first (which you're doing) before attempting more optimized approaches.  Some optimizations that can be done are discussed in Matt Pettineo's [Position From Depth](http://mynameismjp.wordpress.com/2009/03/10/reconstructing-position-from-depth/) article.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had been thinking about this solution a few times already but never tried it.

Comment: @user205695 If you return to the site, perhaps check the checkbox beside Nathan's answer.